# How often should I initialize connections to database

Tags: database, database-performance

I'm using hbase for big data analysis and writing an API for querying it.

At the moment everytime a request is handled a new connection is opened, and a new table is created. Then the query begins. When the query finishes, the table closed and then the connection closes.

From doing the research it seems constantly opening a new connection is overkill.

I'm wondering, since I might have many requests per second, how often should I open a new connection to the database, and how often should I open a new connection to the table?

Does this depend on the database in use, or the number of requests being handled?

Thanks for any help